# Simple rsync incremental backup that timestamps deleted files

Tags: backup, rsync

I use `rsync` as follows:

> rsync -a --backup --suffix="."$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M") *source backups*

to dump the whole of folder *source* into the folder *backups*, with the additional feature that if I modify some file *foo* in *source*, the old version of *foo* in backups will be renamed with a date suffix before the new *foo* is copied into *backups*.

This simple procedure does the job for me, only that I would like a **deleted** file to be **renamed** with the date suffix instead of being removed from *backups*. That is, if *foo* is deleted from source, then rename *foo* in *backups* with the date suffix.

I have tried to achieve this but so far no success. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Adding the `--backup-dir` option should do what you're looking for:

> --backup-dir=DIR
>       In combination with the --backup option, this tells rsync to store all backups in the specified directory on the receiving side. This can be used for incremental backups. You can additionally specify a backup suffix using the --suffix option (otherwise the files backed up in the specified directory will keep their original filenames).

e.g.

```
rsync -ab --backup-dir=versions --suffix="."$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M") --delete /source/folder/ /destination/folder
```

This would create backups of your files at /destination/versions

Source: https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync

Answer (score 3):

Add the `--delete` option to your `rsync` command.  `--delete` tells rsync that when it sees a file that is in the destination but not the source, it should delete it from the destination - except since you are also using `--backup`, instead of deleting the file it will rename and/or move it, depending on whether you've specified a `--suffix` and/or `--backup-dir`.

In your case since you have specified a suffix that changes from run to run, you'll need to add a protect filter rule so that files previously backed up with a suffix don't get get renamed again:

`--filter='P *.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'`

That filter pattern looks for filenames ending in a dot and then 12 digits, which is the format of your date suffix.  That suffix is a bit ambiguous, so I'd suggest using some other format with some special character(s) or a unique string in the suffix, so that ordinary files won't be mistaken for backup files.

Answer (score 1):

For incremental rsync backup used rsnapshot tool.

Sample rsnapshot.conf

```
snapshot_root   /backup

cmd_cp          /bin/cp

cmd_rm          /bin/rm

cmd_rsync       /usr/bin/rsync

cmd_ssh /usr/bin/ssh

cmd_logger      /usr/bin/logger

cmd_du          /usr/bin/du

cmd_rsnapshot_diff      /usr/bin/rsnapshot-diff

retain          daily   7
retain          weekly  4

verbose         2

loglevel        3

logfile /var/log/rsnapshot.log

lockfile        /var/run/rsnapshot.pid

backup  root@localhost:/etc/                   localhost/
backup  root@localhost:/home                   localhost/
backup  root@localhost:/var/www/               localhost/
```

Set Cronjobs For auto backup:

```
# m     h   dom mon dow command
#Run Rsnapshot At 02:00 Everyday
00      02      *       *       *       /usr/bin/rsnapshot daily
#Run Rsnapshot At 06:00 Every Sunday 
00      06      *       *       0       /usr/bin/rsnapshot weekly
```

Comment: At this stage I am looking for a **simple**, preferably one-line, rsync solution. If it does not exist, then I will perhaps (some time in the future) resort to more involved methods.

Comment: You can try following command once you delete source its rename files as per your requirements :) rsync -a --delete --backup --suffix="."$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M") source/ dest/

Comment: Unfortunately the `--delete` option does not work. If you keep modifying a file, say *foo*, time stamps will repeatedly be added to previous time stamps, e.g. *foo.201308121241.201308121242.201308121243* will eventually appear in *backups*.

Comment: @DustByte [balazer's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1204342/702792) shows how to use the `--filter` option to avoid this renaming, thereby achieving exactly what you want. I personally do something like this, with a suffix of the form `_220507~0957~` (`date +"_%y%m%d~%H%M~"`)